# Linking Issue In opencv_createsamples

Tags: opencv, build

I'm setting up opencv 2.4.10 in an [NVidia/Cuda:7.5-cudnn4-devel-centos7](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags/) Docker container. Running `make install` works almost to completion, then I get this error:

```
[ 99%] Built target opencv_haartraining_engine
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_createsamples
CMakeFiles/opencv_createsamples.dir/createsamples.cpp.o: In function `main':
createsamples.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x2cb): undefined reference to `JpgDatasetGenerator::JpgDatasetGenerator(char const*)'
createsamples.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x31f): undefined reference to `DatasetGenerator::create(char const*, int, int, char const*, int, int, int, double, double, double, bool, int, int)'
createsamples.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x773): undefined reference to `PngDatasetGenerator::PngDatasetGenerator(char const*)'
createsamples.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x7af): undefined reference to `cvCreateTrainingSamplesFromInfo(char const*, char const*, int, int, int, int)'
createsamples.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x814): undefined reference to `cvCreateTrainingSamples(char const*, char const*, int, int, char const*, int, int, int, double, double, double, bool, int, int)'
createsamples.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x857): undefined reference to `cvShowVecSamples(char const*, int, int, double)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_createsamples] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/haartraining/CMakeFiles/opencv_createsamples.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am able to get opencv 2.4.10 to work with CUDA 7.0 in CentOS 6, but this issue appears in CentOS 7 with CUDA 7.5.

Comment: Some of the functions are defined here - https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4/apps/haartraining/cvhaartraining.cpp - Based on configuration defined here -  https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4/apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt#L58 - this should not be an issue - can you share other logs from building the  haartraining app?
Alternatively for you to continue you could disable building that if you are not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unsure why this step was necessary here and not in my CentOS 6/CUDA 7.0 setup; I also find it surprising that this fix was not necessary until so far into the `make install` process, but the solution was simply

`make clean`

*then*

`make install`